# Click on element in dropdown with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, screen-scraping

**With Selenium and Chrome webdriver on MacOS need to click dropdown element. But always have an error that can't find. Have this html code on a page where it located:**

```
<select id="periodoExtrato" name="periodoExtrato" class="EXTtexto" onchange="enviarExtrato(document.formperiodo.periodoExtrato[document.formperiodo.periodoExtrato.selectedIndex].value);">
<!--<option value="01" >&Uacute;ltimo dia</option>-->
<option value="03" selected="true">Últimos 3 dias</option>
<option value="05">Últimos 5 dias</option>
<option value="07">Últimos 7 dias</option>
<option value="15">Últimos 15 dias</option>
<option value="30">Últimos 30 dias</option>
<option value="X">Data específica (até 60 dias)</option>
<option value="D">Mês completo (desde 2002)</option>
</select>
```

**I need to choose Últimos 15 dias, so i have this code:**

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="periodoExtrato"]/option[4]').click()
```

**But have an error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "olxscrape.py", line 120, in <module>
    main()
  File "olxscrape.py", line 117, in main
    b = Bot()
  File "olxscrape.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.navigate()
  File "olxscrape.py", line 106, in navigate
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="periodoExtrato"]/option[4]').click()
  File "/Users/Lutchenko/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/Users/Lutchenko/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/Users/Lutchenko/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/Lutchenko/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="periodoExtrato"]/option[4]"}
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.95)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.2 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using xpath here. Try, instead, something like this:

```
 select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id('periodoExtrato'))
 option_indexes = range(1, len(select.options))
 for index in option_indexes:
    select.select_by_index(index)
    ......
```

Comment: Now I understand, a problem is in that element goes after </head> at <frameset>, so it can't find it. Do you know how to locate there?

Comment: Problem solved with self.driver.switch_to_frame(name).

Answer (score 0):

A problem is that element goes after `</head>` in `<frameset>`, so selenium  can't find it. After adding this string problem solved.

```
browser.switch_to_frame('name')
```

And after that

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="periodoExtrato"]/option[4]').click()
```