# Get link with selenium (xpath) and click (python 2.7)

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

For my exercice I must with selenium and Chrome webdriver with python 2.7 click on the link :

> https://test.com/console/remote.pl

Below structure of the html file :

```
<div class="leftside"  >
    <span class="spacer spacer-20"></span>
    <a href="https://test.com" title="Retour à l'accueil"><img class="logo" src="https://img.test.com/frontoffice.png" /></a>
    <span class="spacer spacer-20"></span>
    <a href="https://test.com/console/index.pl" class="menu selected"><img src="https://img.test.com/icons/fichiers.png" alt="" /> Mes fichiers</a>
    <a href="https://test.com/console/ftpmode.pl" class="menu"><img src="https://img.test.com/icons/publication.png" alt="" /> Gestion FTP</a>
    <a href="https://test.com/console/remote.pl" class="menu"><img src="https://img.test.com/icons/telechargement-de-liens.png" alt="" /> Remote Upload</a>
    <a href="https://test.com/console/details.pl" class="menu"><img src="https://img.test.com/icons/profil.png" alt="" /> Mon profil</a>
    <a href="https://test.com/console/params.pl" class="menu"><img src="https://img.test.com/icons/parametres.png" alt="" /> Paramètres</a>
    <a href="https://test.com/console/abo.pl" class="menu"><img src="https://img.test.com/icons/abonnement.png" alt="" /> Services Payants</a>

<a href="https://test.com/console/aff.pl" class="menu"><img src="https://img.test.com/icons/af.png" alt="" /> Af</a>
<a href="https://test.com/console/com.pl" class="menu"><img src="https://img.test.com/icons/v.png" alt="" /> V</a>
    <a href="https://test.com/console/logs.pl" class="menu"><img src="https://img.test.com/icons/logs.png" alt="" /> Jour</a>
    <a href="https://test.com/logout.pl" class="menu"><img src="https://img.test.com/icons/deconnexion.png" alt="" /> Déconnexion</a>
    <span class="spacer spacer-20"></span>
    <a href="#" id="msmall"><img src="https://img.test.com/btns/reverse.png"></a>
</div>
```

I use : **driver.find_element_by_xpath()** as explained here : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602539/click-on-element-in-dropdown-with-selenium-and-python)

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="leftside"]/a[3]').click()
```

But I have this error message :

> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string
>   '//[@id="leftside"]/a[3]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Who can help me please ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were pretty close. But as it is a `<div>` tag with *class* attribute set as **leftside** you have to be specific. But again the `<a[3]>` tag won't be the immediate child of `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='leftside']` node but a decendent, so instead of `/` you have to induce `//` as follows :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='leftside']//a[3]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to have a tag name also. So you should either use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="leftside"]/a[3]').click()
```

When you don't care about which tag it is. Or you should use the actual tag if you care

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="leftside"]/a[3]').click()
```

I would suggest against using the second one, with the `div` tag. As xpath are slower and using a `*` may be slightly slower

Answer (score 0):

i have got a similar problem but i didn't post it so thanks for the post.

the xpath is `"//[@class="leftside"]/a[3]"` there is no id with the name **leftside** in your html.